# FreeImage .NET Blank FileName when not constant

Tags: c#-4.0, freeimage

Can somebody explain me please why FreeImage library is not recognizing my variable as a valid filename for the method Load, I tried the following code:

```
var fileName = "C:\\images\\myimage.tif";
            var dib = FreeImage.Load(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_TIFF, fileName, 0);
```

And it's not working, the object `dib` is always empty (the image is not being loaded), but when I tried the following code:

```
const string fileName = "C:\\images\\myimage.tif";
            var dib = FreeImage.Load(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_TIFF, fileName, 0);
```

The result is successful, the problem is that I need that image path value to be a normal variable (NOT const), because I work with different images each time, and this images could be anything.

How could I solve this issue, or it's a limitation of the library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see, you are setting the first example as a **var** instead of **string**.  Define your variable as a **string**.
I would try that, you dont need the const to make it work I don't believe.

```
string fileName = "C:\\images\\myimage.tif";
```